# Lemmatization corpus in R

Tags: r, nlp, lemmatization

I found there is one package which can be used to implement lemmatization "textstem".
But I am unable to install it.
I am sharing script used to install and error which I am getting.

```
> install.packages("textstem")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/nilesh.ulhas.hulyal/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘textstem’ is not available (for R version 3.2.5)
> if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
> pacman::p_load_gh("trinker/textstem")
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates
Warning message:
In pacman::p_load_gh("trinker/textstem") : 
Failed to install/load:
trinker/textstem
> library(textstem)
Error in library(textstem) : there is no package called ‘textstem’
> docs1 <- tm_map(docs1, lemmatize_strings())
Error in match.fun(FUN) : could not find function "lemmatize_strings"
```

I am sharing below code and error when tried to use Lemmatizationfunction from tm package

```
> docs1 <- tm_map(docs1, lemmatize_strings)
Error in match.fun(FUN) : object 'lemmatize_strings' not found
```

Is there any other approach which we can use to implement lemmatization corpus in R.

Comment: This works flawlessly: `install.packages("textstem")
library(textstem)
x <- c("culturing", "cultured", "cultures")
lemmatize_strings(x, dictionary = lexicon::hash_lemmas)`

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann, textstem package I tried but it is not supporting R version 3.2.5 . Is there any other approach to install this. I tried to install it from .zip or tar.gz file as well. But it is not getting installed

Comment: I would go to the [github project page](https://github.com/trinker/textstem) for textstem and post an issue to see if the author has an older version somewhere that works with your older version of R.  I'd also ask the question if the current package might work in 3.2.5 or if there is a specific reason to require 3.3.  You might be able to make a small modification to the code to get it to work with 3.2.5 or it's possible it may work as is (barring the install check), and just isn't tested for that version.

Answer (score 0):

The **textstem** library is responsible for that, but it seems you have to attach it to the code rather than calling the library.

For the "lemmatize_string" function to work it must be done like this:

```r
docs1 <- tm_map(docs1, textstem::lemmatize_strings)
```